# openfire : not able to start openfire server

Tags: openfire

I just downloaded openfire 3.10.
Installation went properly. But when I launched the Openfire server, it gave me following error during launch:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal JID: chintan_pE
crror starting the server. Please check the log files for more information.

    at org.xmpp.packet.JID.<init>(JID.java:542)
    at org.xmpp.packet.JID.<init>(JID.java:483)
    at org.xmpp.packet.JID.<init>(JID.java:464)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.SessionManager.initialize(SessionManager.java:1349)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.initModules(XMPPServer.java:618)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.start(XMPPServer.java:504)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.<init>(XMPPServer.java:216)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:105)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The input is not a valid JID domain part: chintan_pc
    at org.xmpp.packet.JID.domainprep(JID.java:344)
    at org.xmpp.packet.JID.<init>(JID.java:530)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: gnu.inet.encoding.IDNAException: Contains non-LDH characters.
    at gnu.inet.encoding.IDNA.toASCII(IDNA.java:118)
    at gnu.inet.encoding.IDNA.toASCII(IDNA.java:64)
    at org.xmpp.packet.JID.domainprep(JID.java:330)
    ... 21 more
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$ValueIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.initModules(XMPPServer.java:615)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.start(XMPPServer.java:504)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.<init>(XMPPServer.java:216)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:105)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
Server halted
```

**PS:** I am launching it with Administrator Rights (Right click > Run As Administrator). I am having windows 8.1 pro 64bit. Am I missing some more installs ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

please check your JID,it should not contains some character that is not a letter, digit, or hyphen.

Comment: How should i check my JID?

Comment: connect to  your openfire database(configued when installing), open table "ofuser",check "username" and replace invalid charactors:

Comment: jid references :[XEP-0029_Definition_of_Jabber_Identifiers](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0029.html#sect-idp620400)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by using an XMPP domain name that is invalid. At the time of setup, a value resembling 'chintan_pE' (but perhaps including some unicode characters that don't copy/paste well into stackoverflow) was used. That value is not a valid XMPP domain name. You'd typically want to use a domain name that resembles a 'normal' DNS name, something like "example.org".

Starting with Openfire 4.2.0, the setup will check if the provided value is valid, before allowing you to continue setup. This will prevent this error in new installations.

Answer (score 0):

3.10.1 is released, and you can try new version. I have run 3.10.1 on windows8.1 64 and java7.